# Turtlebot 4 Simulation- Rplidar not working in Ros galactic

Tags: ros, simulation, mapping, turtlebot4

I have problems with de simulation with ros galactic, I can't to generate a map, I believe that the problem is the rplidar, because when I ran the next command

```bash
ros2 topic echo /scan
```

I got this,
[image]

Also when I am in simulation and generating the map, Turtlebot4 does not recognize the objects in the world and I suppose this is why, I do not have a GPU on my laptop.

[image]

[image]

I will be attentive to your answers, thank you very much